# Получение ссылки на документы из последнего поста VK

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet

Надо брать ссылку на документы с последнего поста, но выдает ошибку не знаю как можно исправить(

```
import vk_api
response = vk.wall.get(domain='name', offset='1', count='1', sort='desc') #вместе "name" название группы

get_url = (response['items'][1]['url'])
print(get_url)
--------------------------------------------
    get_url= (response['items'][1]['url'])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: что-то я не припомню чтобы апивк предоставляли ссылки ввиде списка...

Answer (score 0):

В `response['items']` находится массив записей. Так как мы запросили только одну запись, то там находится только один элемент. Индекс первого элемента списка равен **0** (поскольку нумерация списков в питоне начинается с нуля). Тогда нам нужно:

```py
get_url = response['items'][0]['url']
print(get_url)
```

Если обратимся ко второму элементом (с индексом **1**), то мы выйдем за границы списка, о чём ошибка собственно и говорит (дословно: список индекса вне допустимого диапазона).

---

*P.s.* Похоже, что вы не знаете некоторые основы питона. Рекомендую их получше изучить [здесь](https://docs.python.org/3/,), или [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python,)